# Proving Hilbert Cube Is Compact

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\mathbb{H}$ be a Hilbert Cube

$$H=\prod_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}\right]$$

Prove that $\mathbb{H}$ is compact in $l^{p}(\mathbb{N})$ for $p>1$

how to processed this problem i really have no idea

i know that for proving compactness we use

(1) to complete and totally bounded  ($or)$

(2) sequentially compact

Comment: It seems to me, just offhand, that sequential compactness would work well. It's natural to think of the elements of $H$ as sequences of real numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Let $(x^{n}_1,x^{n}_2,\cdots)$ be  a sequence in $H$. The first coordinates form a bounded sequence so there is a convergent subsequence. Not look at the second coordinates along the subsequence we have obtained and extract a  convergent subsequence, and so on. There is a diagonal subsequence $(x^{n'}_k)$ along which each coordinate converges. Call the limit of the k-th coordinate $x_k$. To see that $\sum |x_k-x^{n'}_k|^{p} \to 0$ just use Dominated convergence Theorem. [ the series $\sum 1/n^{p}$ is convergent].

Comment: ..you are proving  by using sequentially compact implies compact?

Comment: Yes, I am proving that $H$ is sequentially compact.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy....sir  if you dont mind can you explain bit more...btw thank you

Comment: For the last part use the following: $|x_k-x^{n'}_k|^{p}\leq 2^{p} (|x_k|^{p}+|x^{n'}_k|^{p})\leq 2^{p} (\frac 1 {k^{p}} +\frac 1 {k^{p}} )$. Now it is clear that you can apply DCT.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy....DCT?

Comment: DCT, Dominated Convergence Theroem tells you that if $a_{kn}\to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ for each $k$ and $|a_{kn}| \leq c_k$ with $\sum c_k <\infty$ then $\sum_k a_{kn} \to 0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy....i am trying but i am not get it sir can you help me more