# Proving Hilbert's cube is compact in $l_2$ space through homeomorphism with product topology

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that the following is compact in $l_2$
$$H=\{\{a_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty} |  a_n \in \mathbb{R}, |a_n| \leq \frac{1}{n}\}$$

I am trying to find alternative solutions to [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3137452/proving-hilbert-cube-is-compact) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006005/hilbert-cube-is-compact). One that came up is using an earlier result on the product topology that states that there's the following homeomorphism:
$$(\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac{1}{n}] , \tau_{prod}) \quad \tilde{=} \quad  (\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac{1}{n}] , \tau_{||\cdot||_2})$$

My solution is as follows (I would appreciate any input on whether it is correct and, if it is, whether there are any improvements I could make):

Since there is a homeomorphism between $(\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac{1}{n}] , \tau_{||\cdot||_2})$ and $(\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}[\frac{-1}{n},\frac{1}{n}] , \tau_{||\cdot||_2})$ using:

$$h(x)= (h_n(x_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$

where

$$h_n(x_n) = \frac{-1}{n}+2x_n$$

then since compactness is a topological trait, it suffices to show that $(\Pi_{n=1}^{\infty}[0,\frac{1}{n}] , \tau_{prod})$ is compact, but this follows from Tychonof.

$h$ is indeed a homeomorphism since it is a bijection, with the following inverse:

$$h^{-1}(y) = (h_n^{-1}(y_n))_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$$

where

$$h^{-1}_n(y_n) = \frac{1}{2n}+\frac{y_n}{2}$$

$h^{-1}$ is the inverse of $h$ since:
$$h\circ h^{-1}(y) = (\frac{-1}{n}+2(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{y_n}{2}) )_{n\in \mathbb{N}} = y$$

$$h^{-1}\circ h(x) = \bigg(\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{\frac{-1}{n}+2x_n}{2}\bigg)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}=x$$

$h$ is continuous: take $(x_n^0)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ and $\epsilon > 0$. Then:

$$ ||h(x) -h(x^0)||_2 = \sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg|\frac{-1}{n}+2x_n-(\frac{-1}{n}+2x_n^0)\bigg|^2} \leq 2\sqrt{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigg|x_n-x_n^0\bigg|^2}=2||x-x^0||$$

so we can take $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

A similar argument works for $h^{-1}$.

Are there any flaws I missed in this argument?

Additionally, if there are other approaches (besides those stated earlier), I would also appreciate knowing about them too. In particular, is it possible to show that $H$ is complete and totally bounded? (I tried the latter, to no avail, including by contradiction, but maybe someone more experienced might succeed).

Comment: But where is the homeomorphism of $H$ onto $\prod [0, 1/n]$? That's the key thing. The fact that $\prod [0, 1/n]$ is compact is obviously a consequence of Tychonoff.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro The $h$ I supplied is a bijection, if I'm not mistaken, no?

Comment: Is it continuous? Is its inverse continuous? These are the two questions you have to answer.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro Indeed - I have added the argument for $h$ (the inverse is similar).